# background:(url) only working on local instance of Vite + React app deployed on Vercel

Tags: css, reactjs, vite, vercel

I'm making an e-commerce app using vite + react and hosting it on Vercel. Everything has been going good for the most part but I can't seem to get my images to show using the background:url CSS property.

Regular  tags work on local and on deployment but background:url only works on my local machine.

Thanks for the help!

All images are in a public/assets/ folder and this is how I'm currently getting the images in  tags.

```
src="assets/undraw_web_shopping_re_owap.svg
```

using background:(url):

```
url(assets/jewelry_category.jpg);

and tried:

url(public/assets/jewelry_category.jpg);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [The `public` Directory](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory)

> You should always reference `public` assets using root absolute path - for example, `public/icon.png` should be referenced in source code as `/icon.png`.

You need to prefix your public path assets with `/`. Otherwise they'll all be treated as relative references

```html
<img src="/assets/undraw_web_shopping_re_owap.svg">
```

```css
background-image: url(/assets/jewelry_category.jpg);
```

Comment: Wow... I swear I tried that a few times! I remember seeing something about that on another thread but maybe I was trying it as "/public/assets".

Thank you so much for this !